# Как удалить строку при определенном условии

Tags: sql

Есть таблица Запросы. В ней есть столбец `Контактный_телефон`. Необходимо удалить из таблицы Запросы строку в которой `Контактный_телефон` в части после кода начинается и заканчивается на одинаковую цифру. Например: `Контактный_телефон` 89651226543 удалён не будет, а вот 89355467625 будет удален, так как цифра в части после кода в начале и в конце одна и та же:

8935**5**46762**5**
..........^............^

Необходимо использовать инструкцию `Delete` `T-SQL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM [Запросы] where SUBSTRING([Контактный_телефон], 4, 1) = RIGHT([Контактный_телефон], 1)
```

проверку на наличие и длину значения в поле уже сами сделаете

Comment: Хорошо, понял. Спасибо

Comment: если ответ вам помог, то пометьте его как правильный